# Validate against list of codes

Tags: php, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Been trying to sort out some basic form validation, have everything working apart from some remote validation. I basically have a list of available codes stored at "/_companycodes", so used the following code as per documentation:

```
$("#register_member_form").validate({
      m_field_id_1: {
        required: true,
        remote: "/_companycodes"
      }
});
```

With the following in /_companycodes (1 and 2 being my company codes):

```
<?php
  var codes = ["1","2"];
  var in_array = $.inArray(value.toUpperCase(), codes);

  if(in_array == -1) {
    $valid = 'false';
  } else {
    $valid = 'true';
  }
?>
```

However this seems to throw errors, i'm pretty certain I've made a really stupid mistake, but after looking at this over and over can't quite work it out… Cheers!

Comment: That PHP won't run at all. Have you just taken javascript and wrapped it in PHP tags?

Comment: wow, I knew i'd done something REALLY stupid, thanks for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation using JQuery Validation Plugin (I supose this is the one you want to use) should be something like this:

```
$("#register_member_form").validate({
      rules: {
          m_field_id_1: {
            required: true,
            remote: "/_companycodes"
          }
      }
});
```

Now for the PHP part, that's not PHP!

Are you sure you want to do a remote check like this? If you do want to, the plugin documentation says it passes the name, value pair to the remote script using GET, so:

```
<?php
$user_code=$_GET["m_field_id_1"];
$codes= array("1", "2");
echo in_array($user_code, $codes);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Naryl, this helps A LOT! You mention am I sure I want to do a remote check like this, I'm not sure of my other options? I need to pull the company codes from the database and i'd rather not display them in the initial pages code.

Do I still need to work out if the user_code is true or false with this script?

Comment: @Nick if you want to check them against a database yup, you have to do it remote like this, the only thing you need to change is the `$codes` array and populate it with the codes from your database. The `in_array` function returns true or false, I guess the plugin will be able to use these values.

Comment: @Nick I just noticed the `return` may not work here, since the validate plugin uses AJAX, i'll update my answer changing it for a `echo`.